# AWS Pinpoint see submitted records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I have integrated AWS Pinpoint in my web app but I can't find the submitted records anywhere in the Pinpoint dashboard.

This is how I'm sending a record:

```
await Analytics.record({
  name: 'Login',
  user: 'test',
})
```

the response looks like this:

```
Results:
  9f2d2900-178c-11ec-9a45-717cf5d64f65: {
    EndpointItemResponse: {StatusCode: 202, Message: "Accepted"}
    EventsItemResponse: {StatusCode: 202, Message: "Accepted"}
  }
```

What should I do in order to see that record with its information?

This how Analytics -> Events section looks like:
[image]

And this is the project dashboard:
[image]

Comment: did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I've ended up using Google Analytics instead